# In Laravel, send a post request with json object data

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

I want to send request with Http facade in Laravel but i can't pass json object data it must be just array.

```
Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/json'])->withOptions(['headers' => $coockie])->post($this->policy_url . $address, json_encode($data));
```

My data variable value:

```
$data = [
    "document" => [
        "customerId" => 1,
        "currencyId" => 1,
        "settlementPolicyId" => 8,
        "storeId" => 16,
        "documentPatternId" => 2,
        "items" => [
            [
              "productId" => 193,
              "unitId" => 2,
              "quantity" => 1,
              "storeId" => 16,
              "TrackingFactor1" => "1214",
              "PartTrackingFactorRef1" => 1053,
              "TrackingFactorHasQuantity1" => true,
              "TrackingFactorValue" => "‏test",
              "fee" => 0
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "payments" => [
            [
                "key" => "Cash",
                "amount" => 445810,
                "attr" => []
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

The error:

```
TypeError Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest::post() must be of the type array, string given
```

Comment: can you show full code what  $data contain and what error are you getting

Comment: @JohnLobo Yes i added

Comment: what error are you getting ? better first check in postman whether api works with this data or not .

Comment: @JohnLobo error:
TypeError Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest::post() must be of the type array, string given

Comment: $data must be array. you are passing string but as per your question $data is array.may be you are modifiying $data before passing http

Comment: @JohnLobo No i changed it sorry.
See code again please

Comment: try Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/json'])->withOptions([
        'headers' => $coockie
    ])->post($this->policy_url . $address,$data); if not working then first check in postman

Answer (score 9):

You may try using [withBody](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#sending-a-raw-request-body) method

```
Http::withBody(json_encode($data), 'application/json')
    ->withOptions([
       'headers' => $coockie
    ])
    ->post($this->policy_url . $address);
```

Comment: awesome, saved me... cant even see 'withOptions' in the docs without really digging

Comment: that's weird, since the docs says: By default, data will be sent using the application/json content type.

Answer (score 0):

Make `json_encode($data)` before sending it to the request.

```
$myArray = json_encode($data);
 $finalData = explode(' ',$myArray);
```

Comment: TypeError
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest::post() must be of the type array, string given,

Comment: ErrorException
explode(): Empty delimiter

Comment: if explode doesn't work for you  use $ary = preg_split('//', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); to ready properly your string. Hopefiully it can help you.